# My photos are gone

Tags: gallery, htc-one-m8

I was sick of photos from web pages I visit being stored on my phone, so after researching I installed a `.nomedia` file.

However, since doing this all my photos from my gallery are no longer there: I can see them in media explorer, but there is nothing in the gallery! Can anyone help? Any photos I take on my camera now are happily appearing in the gallery, just all my old ones aren't there.

My device is a *HTC One M8*.

Answer (score 1):

To see your pictures again in the gallery, just remove the .nomedia file, it's hiding the pictures in the folder from the media scan.

You need to trigger a rescan to be executed by the media-scanner (e.g. by performing a reboot) for your photos to show up. Only thing I wonder: new photos are shown, just old ones are gone – that sounds like a different issue, unless the new ones use a different folder.

New section contributed by Izzy